# Is there a way to unambiguously say "out(side) of time"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, ambiguity

"*Out of time*" can mean a variety of things, but IMO the most common one and the one that will be understood if there's no context is "*with no time left*". unambiguously

In can also be used in music but context is often enough to tell.

But it the case of a time traveler, *out of time* can be used both for the meaning I mentioned and for when he's "*outside of time*" (*hors du temps* in French). I'm using *outside* just to be understood, but I'm pretty sure *out of time* is the only correct form.

Is using *outside of time* incorrect? Is there another way to express that idea that's not (or less) ambiguous?

---

That "problem" occurs for example in the lyrics of *True Survivor* by David Hasselhoff:

> Out of time, running in and out of time

I believe the first one means *no more time*/*running out of time*, while the second one has the other meaning. It's hard to tell, am I correct?

Comment: I wouldn't say *outside of time* is incorrect but instinctively I want to say *outside the dimension of time* or *outside (of) time itself*. I think Marty McFly had the license plate OUTTATIME, so I guess Doc Brown thought *out of time* was OK.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your time traveller, and to avoid ambiguity, I would use the word [**atemporal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atemporal):

> : independent of or unaffected by time : TIMELESS